# I am formulating a gradient dexcent algo. fuction and I keep getting a ValueError stating ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

```
def gradient_descent(epoch, x, y, alpha):
    cost = np.ones(epoch)              #Tracking Costs
    features = x.shape[1]
    samplesize = x.shape[0]
    theta = np.ones(features)
    hypo = np.dot(x, theta)           #Hypothesis Function


    for i in range(0, epoch):
       theta[0] = theta[0] - (alpha/ samplesize) * sum(hypo - y)      #Updating Bias theta
       for j in range(1, features + 1):
          theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha /samplesize) * sum(hypo - y) * x[:, j] #Updating feature weights
       hypo = np.dot(x, theta)
       cost  = (1/2*x.shape[0]) * np.sum(hypo - y) **2           #MSE Function
    
    return(cost, theta)


cost, theta = gradient_descent(1000, x1, y,.01)
```

Why am I getting this error?

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-22d4ca0f3896> in <module>
     17 
     18 
---> 19 cost, theta = gradient_descent(1000, x1, y,.01)

<ipython-input-193-22d4ca0f3896> in gradient_descent(epoch, x, y, alpha)
     10         theta[0] = theta[0] - (alpha/ samplesize) * sum(hypo - y)      #Updating Bias theta
     11         for j in range(1, features + 1):
---> 12             theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha /samplesize) * sum(hypo - y) * x[:, j] #Updating feature weights
     13         hypo = np.dot(x, theta)
     14         cost  = (1/2*x.shape[0]) * np.sum(hypo - y) **2           #MSE Function

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What exactly did you expect to be the value on the right-hand side of the assignment in line 12? When you print it or use a debugger to inspect it, is the value it actually has the same as you expected?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am updating my theta values, so I am expecting the theta to be decreased by alpha/rowsize, multiplied by hypothesis function, and lastly multiplied by derivative of the cost function, Which is all of the row values for a given.  This break wont allow me to pass this step for an output.

Comment: @mkrieger1 is asking whether your expectation matches reality.  An error means that some how, your expectations are wrong.  A key step in debugging is to identify where and why they differ.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, since we can only guess as to what `x1, y` are.

Answer (score 0):

`x[:, j]` is a sequence, so the result of right expression is a sequence, and you assign it to a element in array `theta`, which result in the error reported